# Change views in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm currently developing a little application that uses a login screen and a main screen. I'd been watching how another developers had been made the screen switch, some developers adds and remove fragments on run time, anothers have an Activity for each view (in my case that will be a MainActivity with the main_activity layout, and the LoginActivity with the login_activity layout). And I don't know wich is the way to go. I think that have a fragment for each view will be the solution with more sense, but I want to listen some opinions before continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be others who disagree with me, but in my opinion, **Fragments** are better suited when you want to keep a **part of the screen static and change something in the other part** (**analogous to AJAX** in websites).

**Activities** should be used for individual views in those cases where there is **only one thing happening on the application front-end**.

On the other hand if you have a Gmail like layout *(with static links to Inbox, Sent, etc. on the left hand side and a dynamic list of mails on the right hand side of the screen)*, Fragments is the answer.

But since you have two different screens for layout and main, in my opinion, **it would be neat if you used different Activities for the layouts and used Intents to navigate around**.

Answer (score 0):

For two completely different `Activity`s such as `Login` and `Main` I think you want to use two different `Layouts` and two separate `Activity`s and no need for fragments. However, you may want to use fragments inside any of them as @swayam suggested depending on what you want to do inside of them. You need to look at the docs and decide which is better suited for your needs. No one can really decide that for you.

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)